# Вывод значения в окно, при этом окно запоминает значение, что бы значение можно было использовать в дальнейшем

Tags: javascript, html

Ввожу несколько значений в Input(ы). Там выходит сумма, нужно что бы эта сумма, появилась в другом inpute, что бы в дальнейшем я мог использовать его.
Например 2+5, семерка должна появится в другом инпуте с id например S, что бы далее можно было обратиться к этому значению

Comment: покажите чтоли попытки решения

Answer (score 1):

Используйте событие `oninput`:

```js
function updateValues() {
  var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
  //теперь можно использовать "$(sel)" вместо "document.querySelector(sel)"
  $('#out').value = (+$('#in1').value || 0) + (+$('#in2').value || 0);
  // "+value" - преобразование в число
  // "|| 0" - преобразование 0,NaN,underfined,null в 0
}

// добавление из js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
$('#in2').addEventListener('input', updateValues);
```

```html
<!-             vv- добавление в HTML -vv       ->
<input id="in1" oninput="updateValues();" value=0>
<br>
<input id="in2" value=0>
<br>
<br>
<input id="out" value=0>
```

Comment: Количиство на рапорте<input type="text" name="kolnarap" id="kolnarap" placeholder="Введите колчиство" value="0">
       <br>
       <br>

Comment: А можно этот код, только на JS?,без jquery

Answer (score 0):

Можно слушать kepress с обоих input'ов, в котороые вводятся слагаемые и в обработчике обновлять сумму в input'е S.

```
$("#S1").on("keypress", function() {
    $("S").val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($("#S2")));
});

$("#S2").on("keypress", function() {
    $("S").val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($("#S1")));
});
```