# Вывод значения в окно, при этом окно запоминает значение, что бы значение можно было использовать позже

Tags: javascript, html5

Ввожу несколько значений в Input(ы). Там выходит сумма, нужно что бы эта сумма, появилась в другом inpute, что бы в дальнейшем я мог использовать его. Например 2+5, семерка должна появится в другом инпуте с id например S, что бы далее можно было обратиться к этому значению

Ширина до обрезки

Количиство резов

```
<script>
    function scorerez(){
        var kolnarap = document.getElementById('kolnarap').value

        document.getElementById('kolrez').innerHTML = calc(kolnarap) ;

    }
    function calc(kolnarap){
    return kolnarap / 2 ;
    }
```

Comment: (((Это в HTML))) Количиство на рапорте<input type="text" name="kolnarap" id="kolnarap" placeholder="Введите колчиство" oninput="scorerez()" value="5" >
 Количиство резов<input name="kolrez" id="kolrez"  value="0">
       <br>
       <br>

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод значения в окно, при этом окно запоминает значение, что бы значение можно было использовать в дальнейшем](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577377/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Не стоит задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз, лучше отредактировать предыдуший

Comment: а почему это не сделать в одной функции?

Comment: Я извиняюсь за дублирование вопроса(1 раз тут).Просто еще не умею правильно редактировать.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править".